# Graphing Metrics in Kibana4

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I've added the suggested metrics filter from http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/metrics and can now see the metrics coming through in kibana, so for example I have the following fields:

- http.200.count
- http.201.count
- http.304.count
- http.404.count

along with associated rates (i.e. http.200.rate_1m).

I can create a graph if I add the various rates manually on the Y-axis, but that means I need to know the various responses upfront (not difficult in this example I guess), but is there anyway to tell Kibana to graph the various fields as separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is a "Split Lines" aggregation. If you have a field that you can use to distinguish the data, then you can use a "Terms" aggregation on that field and Kibana will graph a separate line for each unique value found in that field.

Comment: Chris, thanks - I've been using the 'split lines' aggregation to manually add the fields so happy with that, I just need to know how to generate something that can pick up the 'sub' fields dynamically - or how to use a regexp to define the possible fields.